# Git failed to authenticate in corporate proxy

Tags: git, authentication, curl, proxy, libcurl

I`m trying to clone Git repository with the following command

```
git clone http://github.com/apache/hive.git
```

I have correctly set http.proxy variables:

```
http.proxy=http://user:password@proxy:8080
```

But as a result I get the following message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/apache/hive.git/': The requested URL returned error: 407
```

When I turned on curl verbose mode I get the following

```
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying corpproxy...
* Connected to corpproxy (corpproxy) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://github.com/apache/hive.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/2.2.2
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
< Via: 1.1 TMG
< Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="corpproxy-realm"
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 4126  
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host corpproxy left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://github.com/apache/hive.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host github.com: 0xdb7550
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host corpproxy
* Connected to corpproxy (corpproxy) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://github.com/apache/hive.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/2.2.2
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
< Via: 1.1 TMG
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : No Kerberos credentials available
< Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Proxy-Authenticate: Kerberos
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="corpproxy-realm"
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 4126  
< 
* Connection #0 to host corpproxy left intact
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/apache/hive.git/': The requested URL returned error: 407
```

The following line seemed strange to me

```
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : No Kerberos credentials available
```

So I decided to force Git to use basic authentication.
I change source code in http.c(Git) from

```
curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

to

```
curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_NTLM | CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

After that everything goes ok.
So the question is - Is it Git bug or CURL? Or may be it is not a bug at all?

Tool versions:

```
libcurl 7.43.0
git version 2.5.0
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I tried to use GIT_HTTP_PROXY_AUTHMETHOD=basic or git config --global http.proxyauthmethod basic  with no success.  Basic curl usage on the same URL works so I guess it's a git bug !